# Securing Windows Server 2012 from the internet

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2

I've placed my direct internet connection into the public profile for the firewall and started disabling every rule to block all but RDP. The only rules I am not sure about are these Core Networking rules.

Can these be safely disabled on the public profile facing the internet?

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/38MB5.png]

Comment: If you want to block all protocol but RDP why is it on the internet?

Comment: Just need it as an access point into the network. Keeping the foot print as low as possible and then build from there

Comment: Does this server has to NICs? if this is the NIC that goes to the Internet, I think you can safely block all these rules (as they are more for LANs), but always test for a while. Also, where's your DMZ? Also, isn't it a waste to put a whole server just to RDP into the network and then RDP from him to other servers? maybe you should try building an RDP gateway...

Comment: It currently has 4 NICs. 3 local. and 1 public which I put on the public profile. What is an RDP gateway?

Answer (score 2):

You can safely disable anything that you do not need. For example, does your server get its IP address and gateway settings from DHCP? If Yes -> You can not disable DHCP. If No -> You can disable DHCP.

Do you need your server to response to pings? If no, feel free to disable ICMP rules.

Do you use IPv4 and not IPv6 at all? Feel free to disable all IPv6 rules.

Similarly proceed with all rules in the list. Core Networking just means it is related to "lower level" protocols such as ICMP, IGMP, DHCP.

I also do recommend moving RDP to non-default port. You can see it in the event log of a server with static IP address and RDP on default port, that there are many attempts to hack into the machine using e.g. dictionary attacks. Move it to different port and you will eliminate these.